# What can I cook with noodles and soy sause only

Tags: culinary-uses, japanese-cuisine

Fellows all the ingredients I have in my cabinet are:

1)Noodles (containing egg)
2)1 bottle Soy sause 
3)1 botttle Sesame Oil
4)2-3 Onions
4)1 Ginger root

And because I am reallocating I want to cook something without having much leftovers in order to get rid of them. So buying too much extra ingredients is out of question.

So what can I cook with having the ingredients above?

I thought ramen but the last time I tried to make one used too much sesame oil and I did not like it. But I thought I could retry can by just buying pork to make ramen again with the meterials above.

Can you suggest me a recipe having the materials mentioned above; If posssible only them.

Comment: As the close reason says, we don't do recipe requests, but beyond that I wanted to note that your question's a bit unclear. If those are the only ingredients you want, well, you're having noodles with onions, ginger, sesame oil, and soy sauce (unless you want to leave one of those out). If you're having some specific problem within that recipe, though, we're quite happy to help.

Comment: @Jefromi I sure read it as add some items.  "So buying too much extra ingredients is out of question"  "by just buying pork"  "having ONLY" is not the same as "with ONLY".  OP want to add some items but not have much leftovers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cook and drain the noodles with a stir fry over the top.   Do a sesame oil stir fry with the onions and ginger.  Add in more vegetables and or a protein like chicken or tofu.  I have low sodium diet so I don't do soy sauce but you could finish the stir by down with some soy sauce.

Comment: Wouldn't that be low sodium diet? I don't think there's any fat in soy sauce.

Comment: @RoboKaren that too